# Twitter client that can only show tweets with specified words?

Tags: windows, twitter

Does anyone know of a Twitter client that can filter and show tweets that only contain specific words?

I'm currently using Twhirl because it looks good, clean, can be customized (text size) etc.

DestroyTwitter used to have this feature to but seems it doesn't have it any more either.

I really want a Twitter client that can filter out random messages but still show the ones that contain links, so for example I would like to filter to only show tweets containing `http://`.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: if you want to add information, please edit your question instead of adding answers. If you want to respond to users, leave a comment under their posts.

Comment: Comment by @Twitter Question: Oops sorry I see what you did there! More cleaning, sorry thanks.

Comment: Comment by @Twitter Question: Looks like my other responses got cleaned up, OS is windows. These filters only exclude words not only include words, so won't do what I need.

Comment: please **read** my previous comment before posting anything else or I'll have to suspend you until you do learn

Answer (score 4):

Not quite not what you want, but [Tweetdeck](https://tweetdeck.twitter.com/) does have some [limited filtering](https://web.archive.org/web/20170308230434/https://support.twitter.com/articles/20169914).

[image]
<sub>(source: [twimg.com](https://g.twimg.com/about/products/tweetdeck/modal/modal2_2.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Comment by @Twitter Question: Yeah guess I could use TweetDeck to filter containing only http hmm just don't like that I can't customize it much and the tiny text kills me.

Comment: **PLEASE NOTE:** The above screenshot filters things away, for filtering to show specific things, see the buttons in the bottom of a column! TweetDeck is customizable enough and you can increase text size, if other text sizes are small your DPI is set wrong...

Answer (score 2):

Twitterpod used to do exactly what you want *search for tweets with links* am not sure it still does that or not , and its only available for Mac  users

Answer (score 1):

[MetroTwit](http://www.metrotwit.com/) does this, too (not to mention it's nice on the eyes :P).

Answer (score 0):

It's a web site rather than a client, but I have used [twitterfall](http://www.twitterfall.com/) for this in the past

Answer (score -1):

Here's a good option: [DestroyTwitter](http://destroytwitter.com/)

[image]

> **Filter the Noise**
>
> Tired of reading where your friends
>   are? Filter Foursquare/Gowalla and
>   you’re good to go. Someone on a
>   tweeting spree at an event? Filter
>   them or the event’s hashtag.

Comment: Comment by @Twitter question: Or not.

Problem is filters only exclude words not keep them argh! Unless there is some magic trick to reverse it.